# How to approach this loop?

Tags: python, loops, eval

```
t = input()

stringlist = [] 
setlist = []

for _ in range(t):
    stringlist.append(raw_input())


print stringlist


for h in stringlist:
    setlist.append((set(h)))

print setlist


print len((setlist[0] & setlist[1] & setlist[2]))
```

It's a simple program to find the number of common letters between the words that given as input.  Note: This program only works for exactly 3 inputs. Can someone point me towards how I can generalize the last line of this code to allow for as many inputs as is supplied? I would appreciate it if you could just point me towards the answer and not actually give the answer.

So far Ive thought about using a join() to merge the input strings with the seperator being '&' and then put an eval() on the resulting string.

Comment: As a rule, thinking you need to use `eval` is a sign you're going the wrong way!

Comment: Instead of lists you've strings here, but all the solutions in the duplicate thread will still work fine for you.

Comment: Totally stupid to mark duplicates without linking to the actual duplicate!

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary my question wasn't really how to get the answer right.. i just wanted to know how to generalize the last line of code..

Comment: set.intersection is the right way, if you really want to use the & operator you can use `reduce(operator.and_, setlist)` to get the result of `setlist[0] & setlist[1] & .. & setlist[n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put all the input in a list then use `map` and  `set.intersection`

```
l = ["foo", "boo", "foobar"]
common = set.intersection(*map(set,l))
print common 
set(['o'])
```

Full code:

```
t = int(raw_input())

string_list = [raw_input() for _ in range(t)]
common = set.intersection(*map(set,string_list))
print(len(common))
```

Or cast the raw_input as a set if you don't need the list of words elsewhere:

```
string_list = [set(raw_input()) for _ in range(t)]
common = set.intersection(*string_list)
```

Comment: wow this makes my code look so stupid lol